# What's the equivalent of Grunt task runner in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gruntjs, sinatra

Grunt is gaining a lot of popularity in automating tasks in the Node.js environment.

Is there an equivalent for ruby (Sinatra)?

Comment: There are a bunch of built in rake tasks that do precompilation and minification. There are also plugins to listen to changes to the file system and execute testing and other items automatically such as Guard. Is that what you are looking for? Sorry I just saw you said Sinatra, I was speaking more about rails. But Rake is similar to grunt I would say

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rake](https://rubygems.org/gems/rake) is a great task runner in Ruby.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JGinSD to be fair, there's not much more to answer, and Rake isn't going to disappear any time soon.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is **NOPE**.

Sadly, even with Ruby being used more and more in web development, *there remains no real contestant to Grunt or Gulp.* The closest thing is currently **[Thor](http://whatisthor.com/)**, which describes itself as CLI construction tool! It is similar to Rake, but supports mechanisms that are specifically helpful for worfklow automation (see [the docs for more info](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/wiki)).

To explain the lack of a Ruby equivalent, I would surmise most people find it sufficient to create their own custom solutions atop existing gems like Rake/Thor. Thanks to how incredibly expressive Ruby is, this is not a difficult task. **I've done it myself**, for development of a cross-platform RhoMobile app (which is similar to Rails). It actually took me less than 24 hours.